# Convert list of keys and list of values to a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have these lists:

```
list1 = ["a","b","c"]
list2 = ["1","2","3"]
```

I need to add them to a dictionary, where list1 is the key and list2 is the value.

I wrote this code:

```
d = {}
for i in list1:
    for j in list2:
        d[i] = j
print d
```

The output is this:

```
{'a':'3','b':'3','c':'3'}
```

What's wrong with this code? How can I write it so the output is

```
{'a':'1','b':'2','c':'3'}
```

Thanks!

Comment: The problem is that `j` is not dependent upon `i` - the nested loops are effectively a cross-apply where only the *last* value is kept. Compare with `for x in range(len(list1)): i = list1[x]; j = list2[x];` - *now* there is a dependency established. However, see the answers nice approaches to establish a dependency.

Comment: @user1692740: you should accept the answer which is helpful you, this will help you in getting more answers in future...

Answer (score 22):

Zip the lists and use a dict comprehension :

```
{i: j for i, j in zip(a, b)}
```

Or, even easier, just use `dict()` :

```
dict(zip(a, b))
```

You should keep it simple, so the last solution is the best, but I kept the dict comprehension example to show how it could be done.

Comment: Note that dict comprehensions are 2.7 and above only.

Answer (score 4):

you are almost there, except you need to iterate over the lists simultaneously

```
In [1]: list1 = ["a","b","c"]

In [2]: list2 = ["1","2","3"]

In [3]: d = {}

In [4]: for i, j in zip(list1, list2):
   ...:     d[i] = j
   ...:

In [5]: print d
{'a': '1', 'c': '3', 'b': '2'}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed. Only, I'm not extremely versed in Python. What does "zip" do?

Comment: zip(list1, list2) will give you a list of tuples like `[('a', '1'), ('b', '2'), ('c', '3')]` to work with, for more details you can have a look at http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [dict comprehension](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) to do the following in a nice one-liner.

```
d = {i : j for i, j in zip(list1, list2)}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = ["a","b","c"]                                                  
list2 = ["1","2","3"]                                                                                                                        
mydict = {}                                                            
for i,j in zip(list1,list2):                                           
   mydict[i] = j                                                      
print mydict
```